# CSV Python -Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file of service price list where column a = name of service and column b = has price.

I need to make a function like def pricelist("servicepricelist.csv", "servicename") -- the first part states the file, the second part is asking to pull an element in the row of the file like "washing".

I need to somehow, make the washing or whatever service is entered match the csv file column a and then print the value from column b

the output has to be like:

49.95

Please help

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  You should do your own homework.

Comment: What are the delimiter and quote characters?

Comment: Also, this has *nothing to do with the Spyder IDE*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is an extra class I am taking. Not really homework. Kind of an exercise. The teacher is hasn't responded since last Wednesday.

Comment: @Tankobot I don't know what that is.

Comment: @KayaMehta You should still do your own homework. Or at the very least, do some research instead of cluttering SO with a question that has been answered hundreds of times.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider Debugging. Also see [mcve] and [homework](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have not tested it, the following script should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
import csv


def price_list(path: str, service: str) -> str:
    value = None
    with open(path, newline='') as file:
        for name, price in csv.reader(file):
            if name == service:
                value = price
                break
    return value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = input('Path to csv: ')
    service = input('Service name: ')
    print(price_list(path, service))
```

All it does is import the standard library's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, open the file, iterate over its contents until it finds the service, and print out the corresponding price.

Comment: Thank you so much!